# Can I infer type of a property in the delegate?

Tags: android, android-layout, generics, delegates, kotlin

I have this code. It will `findViewById` with a delegate.

```
val backgroundImage: ImageView by lazy { view<ImageView>(R.id.item_component_section_background) }

fun <T: View> view(id : Int) : T {
    val view : View = findViewById(id) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Given ID could not be found in current layout!")

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return view as T
}
```

Is there any way to remove the `view<ImageView>` for something like `view` in the lazy-block? Can I get or infer the type of the property in the function `view()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have

```
val backgroundImage by lazy { view<ImageView>(R.id.imageView) }
```

or

```
val backgroundImage by lazy<ImageView> { view(R.id.imageView) }
```

Note that in both cases the type of `backgroundImage` is inferred from the right hand side expression type.

Comment: It's not what I think about, but it's the result that I'd like! Like that, I don't have to write the type twice.